# Nothing works to enter BIOS on new Laptop

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, asus-laptop

I picked up the new ASUS TP370QL, and I'm trying to get to the BIOS/Boot menu to boot of a USB drive. However, everything I've tried and seen to try hasn't work. Restarting while holding down/spam pressing ESC, F2, F8, F12, DEL and nothing. Even when I go through Windows 10 Settings to restart into "UEFI Firmware" it goes right back into windows. Any guesses? I've been in ASUS Support chat for 2 hours with zero progress other than retrying all of the above.

Comment: If restarting into the UEFI doesn't work, then it seems like a defect rather than a feature. I'd pursue it as such and demand that Asus fix that.

Comment: This is impeding the work I need to be doing right now, I can't afford to sit here and wait for ASUS to fix it...

Comment: what does the user manual say?

Comment: Press F2 while starting up

Comment: Does pressing F2 via attached usb keyboard helps?

Comment: If you don't have a USB keyboard try holding the *Fn* key while pressing F2.

Comment: Power off the machine. And then start and try the keys.

Comment: Try this link...https://www.asus.com/us/support/FAQ/1013015/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a Qualcomm Snapdragon laptop, it is a customized Windows 10 S (can be upgraded to Windows 10 Professional).

There is only UEFI Firmware and there is no UEFI BIOS, so it can not boot WinPE and can not use Windows To Go.

It means it is not feasible through the traditional reinstall system (For example, if you want to install Windows 10 Enterprise Edition yourself).

Answer (score 0):

power it off. Then push and hold volume up (+) and the power button at the same time until you see the menu. Then let off and use arrows or number to choose what menu item then hit enter to select. This was frustrating for me because no forum that I have found says to do this but I guessed it like you would when putting a phone into restore mode. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Your answer is unclear.

Comment: this is the answer on how to enter the boot menu for the Asus TP370QL which is the very question at the top of the forum. I can't get any more clear than that.